# Segmentation fault after getpeername

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I'm studying a simple TCP server in C and have the following issue. My code looks like this:

```
struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
socklen_t address_len;
int connfd, sockerr;
...

address_len = sizeof(servaddr);
if (sockerr = getpeername(connfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, &address_len) == -1) {
   perror("peername error");
   exit(1);
}
else {
    printf("IP: %s\n", inet_ntoa(servaddr.sin_addr));
    printf("Port: %d\n", (int) ntohs(servaddr.sin_port));
  }
```

But when I execute the code, I get a segmentation fault. However, if I swap the printf lines, the port is correctly displayed, thus the issue lies at the sin_addr field. In other words, the issue is at:

```
printf("IP: %s\n", inet_ntoa(servaddr.sin_addr));
```

Any ideas about how to fix it?

Comment: Where exactly does it crash ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz At this line: `printf("IP: %s\n", inet_ntoa(servaddr.sin_addr));`

Comment: Plese update your question with that information.

Comment: Are you sure that the address in an AF_INET type? If it is AF_INET6 this code will fail. This will be the servaddr.ss_family member that you can test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've rewritten my code to better suit the example in this website: http://www.retran.com/beej/getpeernameman.html and it worked out.

I still have no clue about what was wrong previously, nevertheless.